# Geo fence in Visual Studio Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015, android-geofence

I am trying to see, if anyone was able to run Geo fence on visual studio android emulator. When I try to add a geo fence, it gives me a 1000 status code. I have played around with all the location settings option in the emulator with not much luck. However, maps and other location tracking is working fine.

I have tried this code on android sdk emulator and device and it works fine there.

Looking for some inputs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying on the geofencing API from Google Play Services, then this doesn't work because the VS Emulator for Android doesn't include the Google Play libraries out of box. The same workarounds for installing Google Play Services on other emulators (eg. Xamarin Player) may work on the VS Emulator for Android too.

Comment: Thanks @John. Sorry, I forgot to mention that I used the work around to install Google Play Service. Also, the google play service shows as connected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but on Android Studio Emulator. Not sure if this will work for you, but just in case:

I solved it going to *"Google Settings" > Location > Mode*

And changing it from "Device only" to **"High Accuracy".**

This way my app finally worked.
Hope it helps.